# How to compare html inputted value to value of sql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to insert a number in `input` and then when I click `submit` it will display rows of the sql table of which the value of `cardNumber` is the same as the value that I wrote in input. I tried with this code but it's not working, how to fix it?

index.html

```
<form name="input">
      <input type="text" id="number" name="number">
      <input type="submit" id="submit">
  </form>

 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'provera.php',
                data: {url: $('#number').val()}
            });
        });
    });
```

provera.php

```
$broj = $_POST['number']; 

$sql = "SELECT cardNumber, holder, address, points, FROM data WHERE cardNumber = '$number';
```

Comment: Is this all your code?  I don't see an SQL insert statement (or ORM interaction) in what you've posted.

Comment: Not all, I connected successfully with database

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the code you're using to insert the `number` into the database?

Comment: Oh I didn't get what you mean. I don't need it in my database. I want to compare the value of it to certain values in my (database) table and see if there is a match. like this: FROM data WHERE cardNumber = '".$number."' ";

Answer (score 1):

I think you used incorrect params in your ajax data and also you are not passing the correct value in your query. check below code.

HTML

```
<form name="input">
    <input type="text" id="number" name="number">
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'provera.php',
            data: {
                number: $('#number').val()
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP

```
$number = $_POST['number']; 
$sql    = "SELECT cardNumber, holder, address, points, FROM data WHERE cardNumber = '".$number."' ";
```